# Alterar diretório padrão de consulta padrão (específica) em ADVPL

Tags: advpl

Estou tentando criar uma consulta padrão específica onde quando o usuário abrir a consulta o caminho já esteja preenchido com um diretório específico definido por mim. Hoje quando ele abre o diretório sempre é **"SERVIDOR\"**, como pode ser visto na figura abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de conseguir selecionar um diretório específico a ser aberto por exemplo: **"SERVIDOR\PASTA1\PASTA2"**

O nome da consulta padrão que estou usando agora é "DIR". Nele os valores estão assim:

- **Tabela**: SX5=Tabelas
- **Expressão**: AdmPath()
- **Retorno**: AdmArq()

Alguem saberia como ajudar? Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar criar um fonte customizado:

```
#include "Protheus.ch"
Static _REResult

User function REFileAdm()
Local cDirInicial := "\PASTA1\PASTA"
Local cMascara := "*.doc"
_REResult :=  cGetFile(cMascara,"Escolha um Arquivo,,cDirInicial)
Return !Empty(_REResult)

User function REFileRet()
Return _REResult
```

Compilado este RdMake, Crie uma Consulta Padra Especifica (Consulta RE).